# PHP / MySQLi - Catch unique ID conflict

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, unique-constraint

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to check if an INSERT statement triggers a conflict due to a unique index on a MySQL field while performing the INSERT.

For example, say I'm adding a user to a database, and `username` is a unique index:

```
$sql = new MySQLi(...);
$res = $sql->query('INSERT INTO `users` (`username`) VALUES ("john_galt");');
```

A user named `john_galt` already exists, so the INSERT won't be performed. But how can I best respond to the user with a meaningful error (i.e. A user with that username already exists; please choose a unique name.)?

I thought of a couple things, like checking if `insert_id` is set -- which it shouldn't be if the query generated an error. But that error could be *anything*.

Similarly, I could check to see if `$sql->error` is not empty, except, again, that could be anything as well -- a syntax error, or a malformatted value, or whatever. Obviously I'm not going to print out the actual MySQL error for the end user.

The two solutions I can think of are:

- Before running the INSERT, run a ``` SELECT TRUE FROM ``users`` WHERE ``username`` = "john_galt"; ``` to see if the username already exists in the database, but I feel like I added a unique constraint to the field so that I wouldn't have to do this -- kinda defeats the purpose otherwise.
- `strpos($sql->error, 'Duplicate entry') === 0` -- seems horribly hackish.

Is there a better method for determining this using PHP's MySQLi class?

Comment: I suggest doing a validation first before trying to attempt an `INSERT`. Saves more time than doing an expected failure. :)

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be an unexpected failure... what's the point of having a unique field (i.e. besides a primary index), if I have to manually check its existence before inserting another row?

Comment: I agree that this is the point of having a unique field and there's no inherent value in checking in advance. In most scenarios, the valid insert will be much more common than a collision, so it's more efficient to simply do the insert and respond to the error condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [errno](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) to get the returned error code and use that, for example:

```
if($sql->errno === 1062) {
    //do something
}
```

Here's a list of error codes for MySQL 5.5: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of that! It'd be cool if PHP's MySQLi class included these constants on it somewhere so I wasn't using the literal error code.

Comment: Not that I'm likely to need to get that specific, but is it also possible to extract the name of the field, in case there are multiple fields with a unique constraint and the error message should be more specific?

Comment: @MMiller I'm not aware of any way to do that, apart from using some kind of regular expression to extract the field name from the returned error string. The problem using that approach is that I think that even if there are more than one duplicate unique fields, MySQL will only return an error for the first one it encounters. By the way, if you need to use both the error string and the error code, have a look at [error_list](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php) which returns all this information in one array.